# reconnect automatically a network shared foler who was disconnected

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I followed this tutorial : https://www.chrisrmiller.com/mount-samba-share-in-ubuntu/
I modified the fstab file as it says.
to mount a network shared folder in my Ubuntu 22.04. All is ok, but sometimes the distant computer (a windows system) must be off. When I reboot the windows computer AFTER my ubuntu, my shared folder doesn't connect anymore in my Linux computer.. How can I do to have the (re)mount automatically ?
Thx !!

Answer (score 1):

***One method*** is to use an automount directive in fstab.

Let's take the linked HowTo's example:

> /// /mnt/myFolder/ cifs
> username=YOURUSERNAME,password=YOURPASSWORD,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777

Add 3 more options: **noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=30**

- **noauto** = the share will not automount at boot
- **x-systemd.automount** = the share will mount when the mount point is accessed by you, a process, an application, a script, pretty much anything.
  It's fairly seamless in operation.
- **x-systemd.idle-timeout=30** = the share will unmount if access is idle for 30 seconds - you can change this to whatever you want.

The resulting fstab declarations would look like this:

```
//<your-ip-address>/<mount-name> /mnt/myFolder/ cifs username=YOURUSERNAME,password=YOURPASSWORD,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=30
```